# Removing duplicates in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Using Postgres 9.5, I have a table `properties`:

```
CREATE TABLE properties (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    property_id integer,
    state character(2),
    record_type character(1),
    ...
);
```

- `id` is my unique internal id.
- `property_id` is from a 3rd party. Properties from different states may share the same `property_id` but there is only one `property_id` per state. Reason being, the `properties` table contains all states together instead of one state per table and the `property_id` counter starts from 1 for each state.
- `state` is the US state abbreviation (e.g. MA, CA, NY). When concatenated with `property_id` it references one property, e.g. `12345NY`.
- `record_type` can be `A` (add), `C` (change), or `D` (delete).

When new properties are added to the table their `record_type` is `A`. Over time a properties' details change and there are new rows added to the table with `C` as their `record_type`.

Example:

```
id,   property_id, state, record_type, ...
7353, 6001,        'MA',  'A',         ...
7354, 6001,        'MA',  'C',         ...
7355, 6001,        'MA',  'C',         ...
```

**Here's the problem:** I want to only keep the most recent row for the property (doesn't matter what `record_type`) and delete all the older ones. So in the example, just keep the last row. There's no date column but we can assume the higher the `id`, the newer the record. As a side note, all the rows with `D` record types have been previously removed so we're only dealing with `add` and `change` record types.

Comment: It's not clear if the `record_type` (and `state`)  is relevant for the question. Do you just want to keep one record per `property_id`, the rest of the field being irrelevant?

Comment: @leonbloy The state is relevant because when combined with the property_id, references one unique property. I guess the record_type could be considered extraneous information if we're only concerned with keeping the latest record irrespective of record_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by property_id,state
                              ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
   FROM properties)
DELETE
FROM properties WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE rn >1)
```

Comment: This is much more elegant (and probably efficient) than my answer.

Comment: What a beautiful solution

Comment: @Mihai I'm getting `ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep one record per `property_id` `state` pair, irrespective of the other fields, this should be enough

```
DELETE FROM properties p1 
WHERE p1.id != 
(SELECT max(p2.id) FROM properties p2 WHERE 
 p2.property_id = p1.property_id AND p2.state = p1.state);
```

Comment: Sorry I am on smartphone and just touched the wrong place, already undone it (:

Comment: @leonbloy I'm not the downvoter, but I think there is an issue with that query where it can unintentionally delete properties from other states. The true property id is really the property_id and state combined. There may be multiple different properties that share the same property_id.

Comment: @Tyler It seems you are right. I think it's fixed now.